# Проблема Line height с элементами inline-block

Tags: css, css3, html5

По непонятной причине  теги `<a>` не применяют собственную `line height`, а вместо этого используют родительские `line height` .
 Он применяется только в том случае, когда теги `<a>` имеют более высокую `line height`, чем их родительские элементы, или когда для свойства `display` установлено значение `block`.
Я что-то пропустил относительно свойства `line-height`?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .container {
      max-width: 200px;
      border: 2px black solid;
      line-height: 5;
    }
    
    .container>a {
      display: block;
      line-height: 1.5;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class=container>
    <a>First</a>
    <a>Second</a>
    <a>Third</a>
    <a>Fourth</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

*Примечание переводчика:*

Этот топик выбран для перевода в качестве учебного пособия по одному из свойств `CSS`
Автор топика очень доходчиво, на примерах поясняет все нюансы использования `line-height`

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/54341767/7394871

Comment: `.container>a { display: block;` — ну как так-то блин, отсутствие примера с `inline-block` сбивает с толку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`line-height` применяется, но вам нужно понять, как она применяется. Если мы ссылаемся на [спецификацию](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height):

> В элементе контейнера блока, содержимое которого состоит из элементов
>   `inline-level`, `line-height` задает минимальную высоту линейных
>   блоков внутри элемента

Устанавливая `line-height: 5` для родительского элемента, вы устанавливаете минимальную высоту для `linebox`.

> На незаменяемом `inline` элементе `line-height` указывает высоту,
>   которая используется при расчете высоты линейного блока.

Установив `line-height:1,5;`, вы определили высоту строки.

Чтобы объяснить это проще, - у вас есть `linebox` с высотой, равной `1,5`, внутри `linebox` с высотой, равной `5`, но вы не сможете это увидеть.

Если вы увеличите `line-height` для `child` и достигнете`5`, вы достигнете минимальной высоты и начнете увеличивать `linebox`, определенный родительским элементом.

Чтобы увидеть это, вам нужно применить `vertical-align`. Если `line-height` дочернего элемента меньше, чем `line-height` родительского элемента, вы можете выровнять:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 2px black solid;
  line-height: 5;
}

.container>a {
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a>First</a>
  <a style="vertical-align:top;">Second</a>
  <a>Third</a>
  <a style="vertical-align:bottom;">Fourth</a>
</div>
```

Если вы увеличите `line-height`, вы увидите, что выравнивание не будет иметь никакого эффекта, так как `linebox` равен по высоте `linebox` родителя, и нет места для вертикального выравнивания:

```css
container {
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 2px black solid;
  line-height: 5;
}

.container>a {
  line-height: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <a>First</a>
  <a style="vertical-align:top;">Second</a>
  <a>Third</a>
  <a style="vertical-align:bottom;">Fourth</a>
</div>
```

Чтобы сделать своего рода аналогию, это похоже на установку `height/min-height` внутри контейнера `flexbox`.
Когда высота элемента меньше, мы можем выровнять:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 2px black solid;
  min-height:100px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
}

.container>a {
  height:20px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <a>First</a>
  <a style="align-self:center;">Second</a>
  <a>Third</a>
  <a style="align-self:flex-end;">Fourth</a>
</div>
```

Но когда `height` больше и достигает минимума, определенного родителем, выравнивать нечего, и общая высота родителя может увеличиться, если мы продолжим увеличивать высоту `childs`:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 2px black solid;
  min-height:100px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
}

.container>a {
  height:110px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <a>First</a>
  <a style="align-self:center;">Second</a>
  <a>Third</a>
  <a style="align-self:flex-end;">Fourth</a>
</div>
```

Вы также можете заметить, что вы применяете `width: 100%`, которое не будет влиять на `inline` элемент, но будет применяться к `inline-block`, заставляя каждый элемент размещаться на отдельной строке.

Та же логика все еще применима: каждая строка имеет минимальную высоту, определяемую родительской высотой строки, и может увеличиваться только в том случае, если высота строки дочернего элемента больше родительского элемента.

Чтобы доказать, что `inline` и`inline-block` ведут себя одинаково, вы можете вызвать разрыв строки с помощью элемента `inline`, и вы получите тот же эффект:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 2px black solid;
  line-height: 5;
}

.container>a {
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.alt > a{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <a>First</a><br>
  <a>Second</a><br>
  <a>Third</a><br>
  <a>Fourth</a>
</div>

<div class="container alt">
  <a>First</a>
  <a>Second</a>
  <a>Third</a>
  <a>Fourth</a>
</div>
 Run code snippet
```

Теперь, если вы установите `a` в качестве элемента`block`, у вас больше не будет элемента уровня `inline` внутри родительского контейнера, поэтому его`line-height` не будет иметь никакого эффекта

```css
.container {
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 2px black solid;
  line-height: 5;
}

.container>a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.5;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <a>First</a>
  <a>Second</a>
  <a>Third</a>
  <a>Fourth</a>
</div>
```

Добавьте текст внутри родительского элемента, и вы увидите, что `line-height` снова будет определена, чтобы определить линию, где находится текст:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 2px black solid;
  line-height: 5;
}

.container>a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.5;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <a>First</a>
  <a>Second</a>
  <a>Third</a>
  <a>Fourth</a>
  some text
</div>
```

Несколько интересных вопросов:

[Why is the span's line-height is useless?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11829393/8620333)

[I do not "get" the vertical-align css property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54190225/8620333)

[Why is there space between line boxes, not due to half leading?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52280267/8620333)